# delegate method can not be called in singleton

Tags: ios, methods, singleton

```
static LocationClass * locationClass= nil;
loationManger.delegate = locationClass;
[loationManger startUpdatingLocation];

-locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

The .h I have get CLLocationManagerDelegate. This is a singleton class but the method fullface can not be called, could someone can help me?

Comment: What do you mean with "but the method fullface can not be called"? By the time you call `loationManger.delegate = locationClass;`, does `locationClass` really point to an object or is it still `nil`?

Comment: The delegate method can not be called...Before get the method ,I have get the shareclass method;

Comment: That does not answer my questions. When we're trying to help you and ask questions about your setup please try to give use more information. Please use the debugger or NSLog to verify that `locationClass` is not `nil` when you call `loationManger.delegate = locationClass;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating memory by `static LocationClass * locationClass= nil;`

thats why your delegate is not being called. The delegate must get allocated to use.

Try

```
static LocationClass * locationClass= [[LocationClass alloc]init];
```

It will allocate the memory and call your delegate method